# How do I install a newer version of a package on elementary-os?

Tags: package-management

elementaryos 5.1.4 Hera is based on ubuntu bionic (18.04) which contains zfsutils-linux at version 0.7.5.

However I need version 0.8.0+ which introduces encryption. What is the proper way, to install install a single package which is not in the default repository?

E.g. which is the proper repository url to add for Ubuntu 20.04? And how do I install only this specific package from the newer repository?

Or would you recommend simply installing from source/binary directly from ZFS?

Comment: Do you mean 0.8.0+?

Comment: @KGIII yes, of course sry.

Comment: I'd try downloading the .deb from [here](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-proposed-main-amd64/zfsutils-linux_0.8.3-1ubuntu12.6_amd64.deb.html) and then using apt from the terminal to install dependencies - unless you have gdebi installed. If you have gdebi installed, just use that. Both of those will try to automatically fix dependencies. You can try this, but you may end up in dependency-hell, spending hours to get them all only to find out that it doesn't work.